# I want to iterate the row of html table and to fetch the data

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('#tableshow > tbody  > tr > td').each(function(td) { alert(td)});
```

I had tried but it returns the no of td elements but actually i need their values.

Comment: In your function, use $(this)

Comment: `alert(  $(td).html()  )` ?

Comment: If with 'values' you mean the content inside the <td> element, you can use: .html().

Comment: alert(td.text());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the jquery `html()` function. [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
$('#tableshow > tbody  > tr > td').each(function(td) { 
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

**Update:**
If you need all the `<td>` values of first column then you need to iterate through the `<tr>` instead of `<td>` and use the `first()` query function. [Read here](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

```
$('#tableshow > tbody > tr').each(function(td) { 
  alert($(this).find('td').first().html()); 
})
```

```js
$('#tableshow > tbody  > tr > td').each(function(td) { 
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableshow">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ya its working man . if i want the value of first col then what to do ?

Comment: You mean all the `<td>` values of the first col ?

Comment: Then you need to iterate through `<tr>` and not `<td>`. I have updated the answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Loops through every td in the table and alerts the textual value:

```
$('#tableshow > tbody  > tr > td').each(function () { 
    alert($(this).text()); 
});
```

Or you can alert the html inside the td element by:

```
$('#tableshow > tbody  > tr > td').each(function () { 
    alert($(this).html()); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This workes !

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<table id="tableshow">
<tbody>
<tr><td>dta11</td><td>dta12</td></tr>
<tr><td>dta21</td><td>dta22</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$("#tableshow td").each(function() {


 alert($(this).html());
});

</script>
```